# jquery selector to identify button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my webpage with the below html

```
<input type="button" id="ChangeProductButton" value="Expire Product" class="btn btn-default">
```

I need a jquery selector for this button specifically using the `value` attribute. I have tried several jquery selectors using`value`attribute for this button but it doesn't seem to be identified.

Here is the jquery selector that I was trying to use:

```
$("input[value='Expire Product']").click(function (event) {

    alert("clicking expire");
});
```

Comment: $('input#ChangeProductButton'), there should be only one element with each ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector works, your problem is probably that the button is made dynamically, in which case, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', "input[value='Expire Product']", function(e) {
    alert('clicking expire');
});
```

This will work even if the button is made later on.

However if you're relying on the value of the button, you should probably rethink what you're doing. All id's should be unique on a page, so using `#ChangeProductButton` should be an option and more preferable.

Comment: Actually, plain `#ChangeProductButton` would be preferable. Since ids are unique within a document, including the `input` element selector does not bring much to the table.

Comment: Yes, this button is dynamic and your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: i wanted to use #ChangeProductButton, but in my case i have a single button whose value changes based on a radio button selection.

so based on the value of the button, i would execute an corresponding function

Comment: @God_Father fair enough - but you might want to add a class as well, and use the class as the identifier... But if that's how it's working for you, no problem! :)